# Comunicacion entre dos servidores de sockets en python

Tags: python, socket

He implementado un servidor de Sockets en python que atiende a sus clientes 
usando threads.

Pero ahora necesito tener redundancia de ese servidor con otro servidor identico
que hace lo mismo, pero para ello necesito que ambos servidores se comuniquen, es decir puedan enviarse recibir mensajes entre ellos, hay algun enfoque que pueda usar en este sentido.

```
     Bd1                  Bd2
      |                    |
      S1                   S2

c11-- c12.. c13 -----   c21..c22....c23
```

c11, c12,c13 son clientes atendidos por S1 (por threads)
c21, c22, c23 son clientes atendidos por S2 (por threads)

De alguna forma cuando algun cliente se conecte a alguno de los dos servidores
lo que se desea es que se lo comunique  al otro servidor.

Como podria hacer para comunicar a S1 y S2 para que puedan enviar y recibir mensajes entre ellos, tendria que usar alguna tecnica peer to peer. ?

Comment: En principio no hay diferencia entre comunicar un cliente con un servidor, o un servidor con otro servidor. Naturalmente, cuando un servidor inicie una conexión hacia otro, estará actuando como cliente en ese momento. Por tanto necesitarás tener un hilo aparte para ello para no bloquear al hilo que atiende otros clientes. La parte difícil puede ser comunicar entre sí estos hilos. Quizás si dieras más detalles del por qué de esa comunicación entre servidores se podría ver algún posible enfoque.

Comment: En realidad es una prueba que se va a ejecutar en una sola maquina, al principio, se implemento un servidor muy sencillo que atiende a unos clientes

Comment: En realidad es una prueba que se va a ejecutar en una sola maquina, al principio, se implemento un servidor muy sencillo que atiende a unos clientes por threads, el servidor accede a una base de datos sqlite haciendo

Comment: unas consultas muy sencillas, pero este es un modelo centralizado, la idea  la idea es representar un modelo distribuido, es decir dos servidores, dos clientes y  demostrar que cuando un cliente se conecta a

Comment: uno de los servidores, este es capaz de comunicarse con el otro servidor y realizar acciones en su base de datos, como realizar chequeos o inserciones en su base de datos.

Comment: el problema que veo es si  un archivo contiene a S1 y cs2  y el otro contiene a S2 y cs1 donde s1 es el servidor 1 y cs2 el cliente que se conecta a s2 y S2 el servidor 2 y cs1 el cliente que se conecta a S1.

Comment: como pueden comunicarse S1 y cs2 soson sockets distintos o como  puede comunicarse S2 con cs1 si tambien son sockets distintos o como  S1 o S2 pueden comunicarse si ambos  son sockets servidores y no pueden ejercer doble rol de cliente y servidor al mismo tiempo.

Comment: El unico acercamiento  que he observado en stack overflow es el siguiente pero al ejucutarlo no me funciona como espero.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46961472/communicate-between-two-socket-server         no he visto nada mas al respecto, repensando el problema y viendo si sera necesario implementar alguna tecnica de programacion peer to peer.

Comment: Es una prueba a realizar en una maquina (localhost)  un modelo c1--S1--Bd1 es un modelo cliente/servidor centralizado, la prueba se hace en dos terminales uno pra el cliente y el otro para el servidor para comprobar la funcionalidad.

Comment: La prueba se haria en cuatro terminales S1 S2 C1 y C2 y viendo los efectos de las conexiones de los clientes en los servidores y sus respectivas bases de datos